# cant find dkimproxy

Tags: postfix, dkim

I run a ubuntu 22.04 mail server with postfix and want to install dkimproxy which was available in ubuntu 18.04.

Does anyone know what happend to this package cause it is not available any more.
Is it possible to download it somewhere?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://installati.one/install-opendkim-ubuntu-22-04/?expand_article=1

Comment: I was asking for dkimproxy. The link you posted is about opendkim.